# Porting Java object including state (trained LIBSVM)

Tags: java, oop, object, machine-learning, libsvm

This can pretty much be applied to any Java object, but I ask within the context of machine learning and specifically libsvm. I have an SVM trained on one live Java system. Is there a way to get a system to save the state of this sort of object and move the trained object to a different Java system?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure but is it object serialization that you're talking about? If so you might want to look at 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways. The easiest is to serialize the trained `svm_model` like this with an `ObjectOutputStream`:

```
import java.io.*;
public class SerializeSVMModel {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

    // Set up your SVM model
    svm_model model = svm_train(...);
    // ...

    try {

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("c:/svm/serialized_svm_model.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream );

        // Writes the object
        objectOutputStream .writeObject(model );

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (objectOutputStream != null) {
            objectOutputStream.close();
        }
    }

}
```

}

To deserialize the `model`, you use the `ObjectInputStream`.

Another way is to use the [*Java Architecture for XML Binding* (JAXB)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding). In this case, you need to write a wrapper class to be able to access the fields of `svm_model`, because you need to mark them with annotations. This approach is better, since you have a human readable XML output file or other custom formats. However, you would need a lot of further reading for this.